# Velocity template escape XML from Velocity Context

Tags: java, xml, velocity

I have a velocity template, it represents an XML file. I am populating the text between tags using data passed to a VelocityContext object. This is then accessed inside the template.

Here is an example lets call it myTemplate.vm:

```
<text>$myDocument.text</text>
```

and this is how I am passing that data to the velocity file and building it to output as a String:

```
private String buildXml(Document pIncomingXml)
  {
    // setup environment
    Properties lProperties = new Properties();
    lProperties.put("file.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");

    VelocityContext lVelocityContext = new VelocityContext();
    lVelocityContext.put("myDocument" , pIncomingXml.getRootElement());

    StringWriter lOutput = new StringWriter();

    try
    {
      Velocity.init(lProperties);
      Velocity.mergeTemplate("myTemplate.vm", "ISO-8859-1", lVelocityContext, lOutput);
    }
    catch (Exception lEx)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Problems running velocity template, underlying error is " + lEx.getMessage(), lEx);
    }
    return lOutput.toString();
}
```

The problem is that when I access myDocument.text inside the template file it outputs text which is not escaped for XML.

I found a work around for this by also adding a VelocityContext for an escape tool like so:

```
lVelocityContext.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
```

then wrapping my tag in the template using it:

```
<text>$esc.xml($myDocument.text)</text>
```

The reality is I have a very large template and for me to manually wrap each element in an $esc.xml context will be time consuming. Is there a way that I can tell velocity to escape for XML on access to myDocument without editing the template file at all?

Comment: Obviously you ask two separate questions (and probably mix up needs about them). First question is "Is it possible to tell velocity to escape for XML on access to myDocument without editing the template file at all?". And second question is not asked directly but you feel some trouble here. And this is "EscapeTool.xml() is too slow for me. How to improve xml escaping speed?". Regarding the first question my guess is "no". Can you try to use smthng like: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String) ?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this StringEscapeUtils is exactly what is used in EscapeTool.xml(): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.velocity/com.springsource.org.apache.velocity.tools.view/2.0.0/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.java#347 . Then the only thing you can improve is to check what is going on in toString() method of your incoming Document. Can you measure time for `pIncomingXml.toString()`?

Comment: The speed isn't an issue. Its just the manual effort of escaping each element one by one and its potential for error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

What you need to do is to use the [EscapeXMLReference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/event/implement/EscapeXmlReference.html), which implements the [reference insertion handler](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html#orgapachevelocityappeventreferenceinsertioneventhandler) interface:

```
lProperties.put("eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class",
                 "org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeXmlReference");
```

Comment: Fantastic looks to have escaped exactly what I needed without having to touch the template file.

Comment: This was the solution for my need to populate XML attribute values with variable strings that may contain '&'. I just want to add that I needed to include the 'velocity-engine-core' dependency instead of 'velocity'. That kept me from running into issues with needing a retired apached jakarta oro dependency separately.